# How to delay execution of javascript function until JSON has loaded

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, promise

I have a page that chains two API calls, loads the data into `first_data` and `second_data` before executing a `createPage` function (which is several kb of data manipulation and d3.js):

#### template.html

```
<script src="createPage.js"></script>
<script>
var first_data, second_data = [], [];

function getFirstData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/API/my-request?format=json"
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                first_data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                resolve('1');
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    });
} //similar function for getSecondData()

getFirstData()
    .then(getSecondData)
    .then(createPage(first_data, second_data));
</script>
```

The trouble is that some of the code that manipulates the data in `createPage` is showing errors, for example "`can't convert undefined to object`". In that particular error's case, it's because I try to do `Object.keys(data[0])` on some data that should be loaded from the API requests. Some observations:

- If I inspect the data in the browser dev console, it's all there.
- If I just paste the code from the file in the console, the page draws fine.
- If I hard-code the initializing arrays etc for the data manipulation part of the code (to get rid of the `can't convert undefined`, then the page draws but all the graphics indicate that they were populated with no data.
- The page loads fine if I put the the JSON data in a .js file and load it as a script just before the createPage.js file at the end of the body.
- I inserted a `console.log("starting")` statement at the start and end of `createPage()`. Looking at the network and js console output when I load, the `starting` output occurs before the two API GET requests are displayed in the network activity. Is this representative of what's really happening (i.e. can you mix javascript console and network console timing?)

So, clearly I don't have access to the data at the point when I need it.

- Why? Are my `Promises` incorrect?
- How can I fix this?

Comment: You are invoking `createPage(first_data, second_data)`,-`()` will call the function! It could be `function(){ createPage(first_data, second_data); }`

Comment: OK, that was what was wrong. I'd greatly appreciate a longer explanation of why `.then(createPage())` doesn't delay calling the function to when the promise is resolved - I suck at functional programming. And also, does this mean I should also `.then(function(){getSecomdData()})`?

Comment: To add to Rayon's answer: You can also have promises as arguments to `.then`. But yeah - rule of thumb - always have either `.then(someFunction)` or `.then(somePromise)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) expects 2 arguments(`onFulfilled & onRejected`) as `function-expression(OR handler or callback)` as it is a function(handler) which will be invoked when *Promise is fulfilled*

In your case, `createPage(first_data, second_data)` will invoke the function `createPage` when statement is interpreted by interpreter.

Use `anonymous function` as an argument and invoke your function inside it.

```
getFirstData()
  .then(getSecondData)
  .then(function() {
    createPage(first_data, second_data);
  });
```

*Edit:* If you are not passing any arguments specifically to the callback, you can use `.then(FUNCTION_NAME)`

Comment: Well, at this stage I've got to accept this answer because it actually works, though I prefer kazenorin's refactored code. I just can't figure out why it can't successfully execute the ajax functions in its refactored configuration when it works fine in the original factoring.

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming and using promises, you should probably refactor getFirstData (and getSecondData) to the following form:

```
function getFirstData(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/API/my-request?format=json"
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                // Resolve the result, don't assign it elsewhere
                resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                // Add rejection state, don't keep the promise waiting
                reject("XHR Error, status = ", xhr.status); 
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

And then resolve the promises like this (assume first & second data is not dependant on each other)

```
Promise.all([getFirstData(), getSecondData()]).then(function(allData){
  var first_data = allData[0];
  var second_data= allData[1];
  return createPage(first_data, second_data);
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log("Error caught: ", error);
});
```

To make things even cleaner, you can change createPages's from:

```
function createPage(first_data, second_data){
  // Function body
}
```

to

```
function createPage(data){
  var first_data = data[0];
  var second_data= data[1];
  // Function body
}
```

and the Promise part:

```
Promise.all([getFirstData(), getSecondData()]).then(createPage);
```

Notice how short it became?

Comment: I think your second code block may have an error (though I can't see where). FF and Chrome say there's an uncaught exception `(in promise)`.

Comment: Here's the fiddle showing the uncaught exception: https://jsfiddle.net/nw2zsahz/ (look at your console, it should show up after a few seconds)

Comment: The error was caused because xhr.status === 0, edited the answer to make that clear

Comment: `xhr.status` seems to be null  - here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nw2zsahz/1/ (i.e. the getData functions don't successfully execute their ajax requests(